# Is a Jew allowed to sell tours to visit ruins of pagan temples? What if they're part of a bigger tour package?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, travel, business

I'm curious if Jews are allowed to sell tours to places like the Angkor Wat temples, which were places of idol worship (and apparently still have monks wandering about, presumably for some religious purpose and not mere tourism). If the tour is not for the sake of worshipping, but simply goes because people think it's beautiful, and further if that is only part of the travel package, which includes flights, visits to other places in Asia and more, would that be allowed? I mention the point about it only being part of the offer because I believe we allow people to get paid for work on Shabbat (e.g. chazanut, security guard services etc) if that's included in a general payment rather than being specifically for Shabbat services.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visiting sites previously used for idol worship](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43567/visiting-sites-previously-used-for-idol-worship)

Comment: For the Issur of Lo taassun Iti gemara said "להתלמד שאני".