# Why is Rav Soloveitchik saying the names of these false gods?

Tags: avodah-zarah, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

In [this Chanuka droshe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L96rbF-Rsrs&t=26m47s), Rav Soloveitchik says "Ap-ollo" and "Jup-iter". Yet we are commanded not to say their names (Shmos 23:13). We even use "Oyse-Ish" to refer to a certain false messiah.

Another [Mi Yodea question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53630/)  discusses this, but only for the case -- like "Nike shoes" -- where  the actual false god is not meant. In contrast, the Rav is explicitly referring to the false gods. So, it seems that the heter in that other question does not apply to this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/mentioning-the-name-of-idols-and-foreign-deities check out the Q&A which make a couple of useful points - it's allowed for learning purposes, and it's allowed if they are extinct and no longer worshipped. There are qualifications and details so anyone reading this please don't rely on my summary but go click the link

Comment: I guess you could call that "learning purposes", but that seems a stretch to me. The Rav was not teaching people about the gods Ju-piter and A-pollo, just mentioning that them to explain the desecration of the temple. He could have easily avoided their names, just saying "Roman gods", or used a derogatory term.

Comment: Good point. Bare in mind, almost all situation of saying something normally forbidden, but for "learning purposes", can be avoided, but we are quite lenient because if a person has to overly think about every word he says, it reduces his effectiveness as a teacher

Comment: We don't say that about many kinds of nivul peh, nor about the restrictions on saying various forms of the Divine Name. Even teachers are expected to avoid such speech. Why are the names of false gods different?

Comment: That's a good question, that should be asked separately.