Working on space exploration as a Torah-observant Jew - all the names drawn from Avodah Zara
Related: May one use the name of an avodah zara?
Space exploration agencies and intitutions are generally a-religious, but they do have a propensity to use the names of old gods for all their projects.
This presents a questionable situation for a frum Jew. Can you imagine him in shul, at kiddush, being asked what he does, and saying

"oh, I work for NASA, on a project called Project Ba'al. I was also the team lead last year for Project Molech, I'm sure you've heard of it; we sent it to the heavens and is now watching over us [with its amazing cameras or something]. In fact, one of my children went up to Moloch [because he is an astronaut or something]"

Doesn't sound right, does it?!
So, slightly similar to my question on working for the police, are there any interested case studies, books/blogs, personal accounts by users here etc. about the halachic considerations for working in the space exploration industry, specifically when it comes to dealing with all the Avoda Zara motifs?

https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Benei_Banim%2C_Volume_III.35.9?lang=he&with=all

@Sholom very nice responsa. Seems it is allowed, because it's not mentioning the idol itself, and the idolatry has been nullified, although there might be opinions (Sefer HaYere’im, Piskei HaRosh) that hold that it is D'oraita so we still have potential issues. Therefore there is still room for a relatively interesting answer beyond "it's allowed" :)

Similarly, English days of the week and month names.

@Harel13 yes they are brought up in the responsa above, but we are stuck with those.

+1 And f it is mutar to work on Project Baal, are you allowed to use the washroom during working hours?

In chutz la'aretz, yes.

related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37767/reading-books-about-avodah-zarah

Solar system planets are out too. :-)

@יהושעק It's a shame we can't award bounties to comments.
